# Are there any tools that can give a class/struct diagram of a LUA project

Tags: lua

Are there any tool that can give me a UML or table diagram on a set of related LUA files? If it can handle XML at the same time (the project has mixed LUA and XML that work together) that's a bonus.

Comment: Do you mind commenting on why you think it should be closed?

Comment: How would you expect the tool to identify classes/structs (letting alone their relationships)? Lua doesn't have any way to define data types, and fields are often generated dynamically. There are various class-framework-libraries, but it's also easy to roll-your-own and are definitely mixed in practice

Comment: It wouldn't know types, but it would know names and it would know whether its a variable or a function and it would know inheritance using table structures. It would also know custom data types. I have a very complex source code with multiple files that include each other using XML with embedded LUA code as well as individual LUA files, none of which is commented. Something like this would really help me out even if it only partially maps the source code. I'll change "Class" to "Table" in the question to make it clearer.

Comment: "It would also know custom data types" -- how? You can't define data types in Lua.

Comment: You should take an example piece of code and label it with what you expect the computer to be able to produce.

Comment: There is [microscope](http://siffiejoe.github.io/lua-microscope/), but it works at runtime scanning the tables in memory, not in source files. If you point it at `package.loaded` in a typical run, you might still get what you need ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the tool that you are looking for does not exist.